# How do you manage your project life cycle?

Tags: version-control, project-management

How do you manage your project life cycle?

For example: Do you start with a template? Do you use versioning such as SVN as the authoritative source?  Do you archive the projects, if so when and how?   When a project is revived (work resumes), how’s that handled? Do you use automated scripts to do things such as create IIS sites, DBs, archive, launch, etc?

Of particular interest is management of many projects at varying points of development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Development:** We do not start with a template, because the world changes quick enough to make template maintenance a full time job. We do encourage everybody to use the same IDE (Eclipse), so that they can help eachother with their environments.

**Project Management:** We are using GForge to manage our projects. Sourceforge is slightly better, but GForge is much cheaper and has a different licensing fee model. GForge incorporates CVS, SVN, Document storage, Issue trackers and integrates everything nicely. This makes it easy to see where the project is at. Open issues, and closed issues with connected code changes, everything is integrated.

**Versioning:** Although we tried SVN, we switched back to CVS because it fits our needs better and works fine.

**Backups:** Our GForge server, housing all our projects and sourcecode, is running on a VMWare EX server. Backups are done daily on VM level and we make VM snapshots if we feel that we need more frequent restore points for some reason.

**Reviving projects:** This is very common in our business. Every project has all it's libraries and build requirements in CVS. The project always has an up-to-date development manual which describes all the steps to get a development environment running, and has a chapter with all the things which are not default, to pay attention to. We try to build software in an as-default-as-possible environment so that developers don't have to spend days tweaking their settings.

Nearly all projects are built using Maven, which also makes life easy for our developers. Ususally reviving a projects only takes a few steps:

- Download eclipse
- Connect to CVS over SSH (extssh is built into Eclipse)
- Check out the project (default "Check Out" option)
- Run "Maven Eclipse" and refresh Eclipse
- Run unittests in Eclipse to see if everything is working.

**Builds:** All our projects are built on a seperate build server. Every morning the build server does a complete build and tags CVS if all unittests succeed. During the day, hourly builds are made and when there are failures the team automatically gets an email. Usually we use one build server per project, and it is a simple luntbuid server (Linux, Tomcat, Luntbuild).

Both the buildserver and sometimes even the developer machines are VM's. This makes reviving a project really easy. Get the VM from the fileserver, start it up, and you're good to go.

The build server creates daily sites which show unittest coverage statistics, complexity measurements, CVS activity and developer activity (who changed what and when).

All our software comes with self-building database scripts built in. Point the config file to the database, start the software, and it figures out what it needs to do to the database itself. This really comes in handy because the buildserver can just start the software. No special steps needed. Our customers are also happy, they never need to worry about their database, or upgrade scripts.

The whole project lifecycle is managed, documented and tracked in GForge, with the addition of some external spreadsheets for budget tracking because that's simply easier.

Wether you have an integrated project server or not, I think it is really important to have a system. This enables you to switch developers between projects without them getting lost. It saves time. Particularly when a customer comes back to you after 2 or 3 years for modifications on old software (yes, that happens).

All the stuff we use is open source (you can even use an open source fork of GForge). It's not in the tools, it's how you use them.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the nature of the work. When working at home for private clients, I start by opening a folder for the client with a bunch of standard documents, which I customize, such as contracts, invoices, reports, requirements, testing, code repository, etc. As the project develops, I add/modify the directory as required.

If I had to go back to a project, I would reopen that directory, and for any non-common components, create a new directory. For example, if my client had a web application built, and now they need a second application, I would use the same directories for invoices and contracts and create new directories for the code base, requirements and testing.

In terms of backup, I archive the work at any point where I've reached a milestone, with the exception of code, which I back up daily at a minimum. At the end of each project, when I close a contract, I take the entire directory and compress it and store it on a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

i create folders containning the project stages like "initialize software process" on were we placed docs like the bussiness proposal, we use another one for requirements another for the construction,releases,one for meetings minutes, and so on.

We keep those under a subversion repository but it really depends on what metodology you are using, also it depends on how do you handle the configuration management and how organize you want to be. and yes we use template for most of our artifacts so we assure in some way the quality of our products.

Comment: Is this on a common file share? Does management have issues with svn?

Comment: yes we have a Subversion server. if the management needs a file we emailed to them.

Comment: Okay cool.  Our management works with the files directly so we have to keep the docs out of svn :/

Answer (score 1):

As for **source code**, we have it all in a Subversion repository. After each release, we make a branch - new features only get added to the current branch (on which the next release will be based), critical bug fixes are done in the current and the old branch (so we can deliver hotfixes for the version the customers currently have).

As for all **documents** belonging to a release - from the planning & resource sheets to specifications, testcases, user and technical manuals for the software we create etc. - we store them in a Sharepoint portal site. The advantages of this Sharepoint site is that users have access via a website (so no need to grant management access to your repository ;-), you can finely control the access rights, and you can turn on versioning. We also use tagging to mark whether a document belongs to a specific release (e.g. service pack xy) or product, or whether it is generally valid.

Concerning **scripts**, we use several to perform e.g. nightly build plus unit tests (we usually do that for the last and the current release), but also to deploy the complete software solution (including IIS site creation, database data model upgrade,...) on out test servers. These are [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) scripts using lots of variables for paths, version numbers etc. so it is very easy to copy and modify them for a new release.

Comment: We've actually written the nant scripts ourself (there are some examples online, and adopting these to our particular needs wasn't very hard for the developers).

Comment: Sorry, I meant by find, how was your experience with them.  Sounds like it was good though?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question ;-) Yes, I think that the nant scripts are a good thing - they are time savers, very flexible, and let you do a whole lot of things, and I think they are quite easy to understand and modify (once they exist ;) even for non-programmers.